# solve $y'=\frac{2x+y-1}{x+y+2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-fractions

I need some help solving this differential equation, I'm doing everything as I was taught but I just need help at the last step, I can't seem to get this right. the ode we want to solve is $$y'=\frac{2x+y-1}{x+y+2}$$

if $2x+y-1=0$ and $x+y+2=0$ then $x=3$ and $y=-5$, we can now define $\tilde x = x-3$ and $\tilde y = y+5$  notice that $\tilde y' = y'$, and now we have a new differential equation:

$$\tilde y'= \frac{2\tilde x +6 +\tilde y-5-1}{\tilde x+3+\tilde y -5+2}=\frac{2\tilde x+\tilde y}{\tilde x+\tilde y}=\frac{2+\frac{\tilde y}{\tilde x}}{1+\frac{\tilde y}{\tilde x}}$$.

this is an homogenous ode that we can solve as one, define $z=\frac{ \tilde y}{\tilde x}$, and we have $z+\tilde xz'=\frac{2+z}{1+z}$

which simplifies to $\tilde x z' =\frac{2-z^2}{1+z}$. This is an ODE with separable variables, this simplifies to $\int \frac{1+z}{2-z^2}dz=\int \frac{1}{\tilde x}d \tilde x$

the RHS is simply $\ln |\tilde x|+c$

The LHS can be done using partial fractions, and the result i got was (after some simplification): $$-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ln{(\frac{\sqrt 2-z}{\sqrt 2 +z})}-\frac{1}{2}\ln{(2-z^2)}=\ln |\tilde x|+c$$

And now I'm not sure what to do. It is possible that i misscalculated the LHS integral, but if I didn't and my result is correct, I'm not sure how to proceed. The best we can do in this case is give an implicit formula rather than a direct. The best I can come up with is transfer back from $z$ to $y$ and $x$ and give an answer implicitly.

Is that really the answer?

Comment: Indeed you need to back sub $z$ in the way of how you defined $z$ The answer will be in implicit form. You can't solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ Without going to the rudiments, I compared your exercise with one of mine which I have in my archive and the steps looks right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution on implicite form is shown below :

[image]

Comment: Why did you insert the answer as a picture rather than with LaTeX? Just curious.

Comment: @Skeleton Bow : Just to save time. I was on the verge to leave for several days : not enough time to LaTex.

Comment: How does this actually save time? Did you do it in a program that allows you to make these equations faster than typing the LaTeX out? I'm asking because I sometimes need to write out a *lot* of equations and sometimes just don't have the time to do it!

Comment: Not really : I am used to write the equations with the software "Math Type" instead of handwriting to avoid mistake due to bad handwriting. When the solution is found, generally I rewrite the whole in LATEX, which is boring and takes time. But, in case of lack of time, the copy of the page of Math Type is quite ready to be posted.

Comment: That's a great suggestion! I'll try MathType out. It should be really helpful for me when I need to write a lot. Thank you very much!